# Empty table of contents

Tags: vb.net, aspose, is-empty, tableofcontents, aspose.words

I have the following problem: I'd like to create a dynamic table of content using aspose.words and vb.net.
I did it using this code:

```
Dim doc As New Document()
Dim builder As New DocumentBuilder(doc2)
builder.InsertTableOfContents("""\o ""1-3"" ""\h ""\z ""\u")
builder.InsertBreak(BreakType.PageBreak)
[...]
doc.UpdateFields()
doc.Save(tempPath, SaveFormat.Docx)
```

and it works.
The problem is that when no table of content entries are found I obtain in my docx:

```
No table of contents entries found.
```

Is it possible to write something like that (pseudo-code):

```
If (no_entries_found) Then
    table_of_content.display=false
Endif
```

Thanks so much,

Daniele

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I resolved using a workaround... if the content is equal to "No table of contents entries found." i replace it with "". 
If someone has better ideas I'll be glad to hear them.